# Updating version in android app

Tags: java, android, xml

So, here's the problem. I made a simple game for android using java. I published the version 1.0 successfully in play store, as I did the 1.1. But now I was about to publish the 1.2, **but android studio is giving me the error message:**

Error:XML version "1.2" is not supported, only XML 1.0 is supported.
Error:Cannot read packageName from E:\TomasCardoso\Documents\Tomas\Apps\Discordia\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

**I changed the version name in the manifest file like so:**

```
<?xml version="1.2" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.tomascardoso.discordia">

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".StartingScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".GameScreen" />
    <activity android:name=".GameOverScreen" />
    <activity android:name=".Tutorial"/>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

And changed the build gradle like so:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tomascardoso.discordia"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.2"
 }
```

If I change the "1.2" to "1.1" it works just fine, but with "1.2" it gives those error messages.

Comment: You changed wrong place. <?xml version="1.2" encoding="utf-8"?>. XML version must be 1.0

Comment: don't update xml version. Refer this link to understand how to version your app https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html

Comment: change this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in your manifest file.

Comment: thanks, it works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing version of xml in manifest file

```
<?xml *version="1.2"* encoding="utf-8"?>
```

part in star has problem

replace version to 1.0

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: @TomásCardoso If an answer helped you, you should accept the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change in the **manifest** version="1.2"
to version="1.0"

hope it will help

Comment: 'hope it will help' if you are unsure if your answer is helpful rather consider putting it as an comment to prevent down-votes. If you don't have sufficient reputation to put a comment consider not putting an answer if you are unsure.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

> To define the version information for your app, set values for the version settings in the Gradle build files. These values are then merged into your app's manifest file during the build process.

Two settings are available, and you should always define values for both of them:

> versionCode — An integer used as an internal version number. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent versions.You can set the value to any integer you want, however you should make sure that each successive release of your app uses a greater value.
>
> versionName — A string used as the version number shown to users. This setting can be specified as a raw string or as a reference to a string resource.
>   The value is a string so that you can describe the app version as a .. string, or as any other type of absolute or relative version identifier. The versionName has no purpose other than to be displayed to users.

What you need to do is set versionCode value in build.gradle file higher than your previous versionCode. Change your xml version in manifest file to 1.0 as it was earlier.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had to change in both of them

Comment: Can u please accept this answer, if it solved your problem??